# Setting setAttribute() for line formatting, line_spacing, SPACING_AFTER, SPACING_BEFORE

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to generate a report in a Google doc from a template file. When it copies the document it resets all of the formatting to the defaulted for the user and not what the format in the original doc is. I've tried the following to try and set the formatting on a both the document, tableRow and tableCell level though when the report is created the line spacing is 1.5 and there is a space after paragraph

```
var style = {};
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.SPACING_AFTER] =0;
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.SPACING_BEFORE] =0;
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.LINE_SPACING]=1;   

var newrow= tables[2].insertTableRow(n).setBold(false).setAttributes(style);
   if(j==0){
     newrow.insertTableCell(0,reportDate).setPaddingBottom(0).setPaddingTop(0).setAttributes(style);
   }
   else{
     newrow.insertTableCell(0,'').setPaddingBottom(0).setPaddingTop(0).setAttributes(style);
   }
   newrow.insertTableCell(0,values1[rowId1][1]+' '+values1[rowId1][2]).setPaddingBottom(0).setPaddingTop(0).setAttributes(style);
   newrow.insertTableCell(0,'').setPaddingBottom(0).setPaddingTop(0).setAttributes(style); 
   doc.editAsText().setAttributes(style);
```

any suggestions on how to have the report follow these attributes?

Comment: Can you share how you copy the document? Perhaps something is going awry there.

Comment: var file = DocsList.getFileById('1DIfn_wVpXSI4hU5zG43Fvp2ZdpUP_KqgtgFRT9NWJ7E ');       var newFile = DocsList.copy(file, ename+'-'+reportDate+'Monthly Report'); var a=newFile.getId(); var doc = DocumentApp.openById(a);

Comment: I am still unable to see this problem. I just tried to copy a "template" file using the code above and it retained all the original formatting including the line spacing. Is your issue that you are not able to achieve the formatting you want via Apps Script or formatting (spacing) is lost when you copy over a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the set attributes was not setting the attributes and you can not cast any of the elements as paragraphs I resolved this problem by getting all of the paragraphs and setting them manually by adding this at the end

```
var p=doc.getParagraphs();
  for(i=0;i<p.length; i++){
    p[i].setLineSpacing(1).setSpacingAfter(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the SPACING_AFTER, SPACING_BEFORE & LINE_SPACING are not attributes associated with the TABLE_CELL object. You must reference the child PARAGRAPH in order to set these.

```
var style = {};
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.SPACING_AFTER] =0;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.SPACING_BEFORE] =0;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.LINE_SPACING]=1;   

  var newrow = tables[2]
    .insertTableRow(n)
    .setBold(false);

  if (j == 0) {
    newrow.insertTableCell(0,reportDate)
      .setPaddingBottom(0)
      .setPaddingTop(0);
  }
  else {
    newrow.insertTableCell(0,'').setPaddingBottom(0).setPaddingTop(0);
  }
  newrow.insertTableCell(0,values1[rowId1][1]+' '+values1[rowId1][2])
    .setPaddingBottom(0)
    .setPaddingTop(0);
  newrow.insertTableCell(0,'')
    .setPaddingBottom(0)
    .setPaddingTop(0); 
  var newrowTableCell = newrow.getChild(0);
  var newrowParagraph = newrowTableCell.getChild(0).setAttributes(style);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! paragraph.setAttributes(style) doesn't seems to be working. After adding getChild(0) and then setting the attributes works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do the users need to be able to edit the report, or just view it? Why not generate a pdf? Every time I've done it, it saves the formatting.

```
var file = DocsList.getFileById('1DIfn_wVpXSI4hU5zG43Fvp2ZdpUP_KqgtgFRT9NWJ7E');
var newFile = DocsList.copy(file, ename+'-'+reportDate+'Monthly Report');
var report=DocsList.createFile(newFile.getAs("application/pdf")).rename(newFile.getName() + ".pdf");
var a = report.getID();
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(a);
```