# What attribute could be causing the padding in this table?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm generating a document from gCal data and I cannot figure out what's causing the extra padding under the text.

In the pic, you'll see I've selected some text for the screenshot and the height of the selection is almost double the size of the height of the text.

[Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3F1J8tkgNUaaEFLclpicDRIWVE/edit?usp=sharing)

```
var entriesTableStyle = {};
    entriesTableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_BOTTOM] = 0;
    entriesTableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_TOP] = 0;
    entriesTableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_RIGHT] = 0;
    entriesTableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_LEFT] = 0;
    entriesTableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BORDER_WIDTH] = 1;
  // Date
  var entryDateStyle = {};
    entryDateStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
    entryDateStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 14;
    entryDateStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_BOTTOM] = 0;
    entryDateStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.WIDTH] = 140;
    entryDateStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_BOTTOM] = 0;
    entryDateStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_TOP] = 0;
    entryDateStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_RIGHT] = 0;
    entryDateStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_LEFT] = 0;
    entryDateStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.MINIMUM_HEIGHT] = 25;
  // Title
  var entryTitleStyle = {};
    entryTitleStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 12;
    entryTitleStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.MINIMUM_HEIGHT] = 0;
    entryTitleStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT; 
    entryTitleStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.LINE_SPACING] = 3;
    entryTitleStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.MINIMUM_HEIGHT] = 13;
    entryTitleStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = DocumentApp.FontFamily.UBUNTU;
  // entryTimes
  var entryTimesStyle = {};
    entryTimesStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
    entryTimesStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 10;
    entryTitleStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.MINIMUM_HEIGHT] = 12;

  // entryDescription
  var entryDescriptionStyle = {};
    entryDescriptionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.ITALIC] = true;
    entryDescriptionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 10;
    entryDescriptionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.INDENT_FIRST_LINE] = 40;
    entryDescriptionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.INDENT_START] = 40;
    entryDescriptionStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.MINIMUM_HEIGHT] = 10;
```

Comment: are you able to reduce the padding manually from the doc UI ?

Comment: Nope, it will only let me make it larger. Although, If I select some text and go to "Line Spacing" -> "Remove space after paragraph". I am able to remove the padding.

Comment: then I'm afraid you won't be able to do it with script...GS is based on the same API and can generally do less (or equal but not 'more') than the original UI

Comment: ah ! sorry, I didn't see your entire comment... then it is worth trying !!

Comment: I think I have an answer. You gave me some insight. I never thought to analyze the document attributes after modifying the layout manually.

Comment: I found a workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310412/setting-setattribute-for-line-formatting-line-spacing-spacing-after-spacing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appears I was trying to set the style on a TABLE_CELL where I should have been setting the style of the PARAGRAPH.

```
    var entryTitle = events[i].getTitle();
    var entryTimes = shortTime(events[i].getStartTime(),2) + " - " + shortTime(events[i].getEndTime(),2);
    var entryHoursWorked = ((events[i].getEndTime() - events[i].getStartTime())/(1000*60*60)%24);
    var row2 = entriesTable.appendTableRow();
    row2.appendTableCell(entryTitle).setWidth(140);
    var row2Cell1Paragraph = row2.getChild(0).getChild(0);

    row2Cell1Paragraph.setAttributes(entryTimesStyle);

    row2.appendTableCell(entryTimes + "\t\t" + entryHoursWorked + "hr(s)")
    var row2Cell2Paragraph = row2.getChild(1).getChild(0);

    row2Cell2Paragraph.setAttributes(entryTimesStyle);
```

A TABLE_CELL doesn't have the same attributes as a PARAGRAPH which is why nothing was ever set properly.